# Inductive limit topology, open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be LCH. Define a topology on $C_c(X)$ (continuous functions with compact support) by 
$$\mathcal{T}=\{U \subset C_c(X): \ \text{for any} \ K \Subset X, \quad U \cap C_c(K) \ \ \text{is open in} \quad C_c(K)\}$$

Here $C_c(K)$ is the Banach space with sup-norm, $K$ is compact. Does $\mathcal{T}$ contain open sets of $C_c(K)$? Does this topology coincide with the one generated by seminorms $p_K=||\cdot||_K$?

E.g. take $B_K=\{f \in C_c(K) : ||f||_K < \epsilon\}$, then for $K' \Subset X$ with $K \cap K' \neq \emptyset$

$$B_K \cap C_c(K') = \{f \in C_c(K\cap K') : ||f||_K < \epsilon\}$$
Is the above set open in $C_c(K')$? In the above set $||\cdot||_K = ||\cdot||_{K'}$

Comment: You are going to need som fancy footwork to get $U\cap C_c(K)$ to be anything other than empty.

Comment: In other words the definition needs a re-write.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should delete this post and review things... but the definition seems ok. Here is a similar thing

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164007/test-functions-with-wrong-topology-not-locally-convex